# How to call a Rest Service in C++?

Tags: c++, wcf, web-services, rest

I want to call a rest service written in WCF (which can support both XML and JSON Web Message Formats) from my C++ application.

What is the best solution to achieve this ? I have seen some utilities (gsoap) which create proxy classes for you to be used to call web services.

Can I achieve the same functionality without using any intermediate utility ? As its a rest service and it works using GET/PUT functions which are basic HTTP functions, is there any C++ library/Solution which could be used to invoke these function directly from a c++ application ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Linux, you probably could use [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) library (and I guess it is ported to Windows). Curl is a library providing HTTP client functionality to a C or C++ program.

Comment: This sounds sensible to me - CURL is a pretty powerful library for HTTP programming.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Casablanca](http://casablanca.codeplex.com/). This should be helpful for people looking for this answer in 2013. CURL is perfectly appropriate but if you're doing C++ in Windows and using MS stuff, Casablanca seems fit.

Comment: Casablanca does not seem to work for C++, but only for C++.NET

Comment: No. It also supports macOS, iOS, Linux and Android. https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki

Comment: It works for C++, I am just going through examples and have no issues.  VS2017

Answer (score 2):

I tried gsoap myself but it became difficult to maintain cross platform versions of my app.
Instead i went the HTTP request route.
For cross platform and C++ i found this [Call Rest Web Services from C++](http://itcompiles.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Hope the following articles might be of help to you

[1. Accessing an XML Web Service Using C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290758%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

[2. SOAP client for C++](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/SoapClient_CPP.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If XML serialization with your REST approach is really not needed then curl is perfect to use. However, if you want type-safe XML serialization in C or C++ then it would become cumbersome to use curl, since you will have to use something that runs on top of curl to process XML such as with a DOM parser (slow and not type safe). If you have a WSDL, then I recommend gSOAP 2.8 which provides integrated REST and XML serialization capabilities (and JSON when you need it).